# Options for subnet w/o internet access accessible by all computers on network w/ internet

Tags: networking, lan

Net diagram:

[image]

I want a computer on my 'normal' network N1 (where all machines have internet access) to also simultaneously be able to connect to N2, a 'subnet' (not sure if this is the right word?) where all the machines connected there are on a LAN, but they do not have internet access.

What are my options to set this up?

The machines on N2 would have RDP, VNC, etc servers running that N1 computers could connect to.

Current network hardware is a single Apple Airport router.  Can buy more hardware if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the edit techie.  Couldn't embed with < 10 posts.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer on N1 only has one NIC (network interface card), buy and install another one. Plug the new NIC into the N2 switch and assign the NIC an address on the N2 network (or let it get one automatically if you have DHCP set up on N2).

Comment: This will allow both connections simultaneously? Are there OS limitations?

Comment: Yes, it will allow both simultaneously. I'm not sure what you mean by OS limitations, but it should work on all the major OSes.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the gateway from N2 machines, then they will not access Internet but all will be in one LAN segment.
Put all machines in one LAN segment, for example in 192.168.10.xxx and do not set the gateway on N2 machines. It will works for sure.

Comment: And if he still wants DHCP auto-configuration for some of the devices, they should be mapped according to their MAC. I don't know though what options there are in Apple Airport Extreme.

Comment: This sounds like a solid option that doesn't require extra hardware.  Unclear if I can do a DHCP/MAC config with the Airport, but I'm fine just manually setting them.

Comment: I've doubt that you may set it on no-matter-what DHCP server, but my point was to do it manually. If you need that I may check? Alen so, adding second NIC on same machine is a must to be on different LAN segment or should be added a router software (at least in Windows). It will work even in same segment, but you may expect unexpected behavior and weirdness in your network.

Comment: This should work, but depending on how important it is that the computers on N2 don't have internet access, it may not be the best idea, as software on those computers could potentially just change the network settings to add a gateway.

Comment: Yes, software or a human been :) it is possible of course. Am not familiar with Apple Airport router but it should has restriction's ability, so it may be set there.

Comment: How did you resolve that? Am just curious :)